# Android - How to set the right on click event to a button that was made programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've made the next layout xml code which I call it `layout_one`   -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/layout_one"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textView1"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                      android:text="Testing 1"
                      android:textSize="20sp" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button1"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Button" />

              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:id="@+id/info_layout"
                  android:visibility="gone">

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textView2"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="TextView" />

              </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see there are two layout in it - one with `textview` and `button` and one with `textview`.

The layout with the only textview - is gone, And i want by a click on the button, from the visible layout, it will be shown.

Now at the activity i wrote the next code -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

  LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
  ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            sv.addView(ll);
            LinearLayout newView0 = (LinearLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_one, null);
            LinearLayout newView1 = (LinearLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_one, null);
            LinearLayout newView2 = (LinearLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_one, null);
            LinearLayout newView3 = (LinearLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_one, null);
            ll.addView(newView0);
            ll.addView(newView1);
            ll.addView(newView2);
            ll.addView(newView3);
            setContentView(sv);
            newView1.findViewById(R.id.layout_one).setBackgroundColor(0xff0000ff);
           TextView tv3 = (TextView) newView3.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           tv3.setText("Suprise Suprise");

           infoLay = (View) findViewById(R.id.info_layout);


           ll.addView(newView3);
```

}

Now there is something I don't understad -  How could I set an on click listener to the button that will  know which layout to show?

Tanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are three linear layouts, which seems redundant.
You can set the onclick listener by checking if textview of each layout is empty or not.

Comment: No they aren't redundant. Each one of them have a button and hidden layout - by pressing the button of one layout I want to make it's hidden layout been shown. So in the mean while I'm testing it with one button. But how would you Define the onclicklistener for the button and where? I don't get what you trying to say

Comment: I think he's saying that your top level LinearLayout is useless, because it only has one child (another LinearLayout).  Also, your LinearLayout with just 1 TextView is useless for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

First off, have a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html.  Use that `<include>` tag instead of dynamically creating all these layouts in your Activity class.  Define your ScrollView, and all your LinearLayouts in your test_layout.xml file.

Then, in your Activity, all you have to do is get a reference to those views that's you've defined using `findViewById`.

Once you've got that working we can address your question as follows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
LinearLayout layout3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ((View)view.getParent().getParent()).findViewById(R.id.textView2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

layout1.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(listener);
layout2.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(listener);
layout3.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(listener);
```

I'd also add that it seems like you're trying to create a list here, in which case you should use a ListView instead of many LinearLayouts.

Comment: I tell you what ami trying to do - I'm trying to create a dynamically view because I can't know how many layout will be - could be 10, could be 20.  The Thing I get the most problem is with creating a rich layout for expandable list view. I want to have the title with much more thing than a simple textview and also the expended layout need to be rich with view items. Couldn't find any example for rich expandable list view that can work also with datd from DB. That's why I'm trying this code

Comment: Then you want to use a ListView, that simplifies your code by a lot.  Here is a tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/.  You can make the layouts in that example as rich as you want, and also load the data from DB.

Comment: Yeah I've tried this code but couldn'u understand how can i pass info from the Db to listItems- Yout see it uses hashmap and list of strings, but it isn't clear how do i pass tow values from the db into the groupview, or how to make one layout for the expendble view and not 3 or 5 lines. I even asked it here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739692/android-how-to-get-expandable-list-view-work-with-cursor - but no one answered me

Comment: You need to create a List and HashMap the same way they do in the tutorial in `prepareListData()`.  You just load it from  your DB instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Ok, but there it pass only one value to the Groupview -like Top 250- What if Iwant to pass more than one value. also at the childView i wanty to pass few values but i want it to go into one layout and not having 5 rows under the opened view- Do u see what I mean?

Comment: You need to define your own class then to hold those values and instead of passing a `List<String>` you pass a `List<MyClass>`.  If you just want one item when expanded, then don't pass a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`, instead pass a `HashMap<String, MyClass>`.

Comment: Actually, if both your Header and Child will be using the same class, you don't even need to pass the `HashMap`, just work with your `List<MyClass>`.

Comment: Well first of all thank you for your help -But still there are many changes to be made like at the getChild  or getChildrenCount - it's not so easy to understand to a young developer like me I guess you can undesratnd by my Reputation that I'm not at your high level - So I will try to see if I can do it now. Shame htere's no way I could ask you things After I will do some test with the code. Yet again Thank your for your help